# Rake task depend on other rake task

Tags: ruby, rake

I have rake tasks which provide functionality for Git. I would like to be able to call `rake git:pull` which should recognize that the directory `@source_dir` does not exist and then it will call `git:clone` before attempting `git:pull`. It is possible to add such a dependency to my tasks?

```
namespace :git do
  desc "Download and create a copy of code from git server"
  task :clone do
    puts 'Cloning repository'.pink
    sh "git clone -b #{@git_branch} --single-branch #{@git_clone_url} #{@source_dir}"
    puts 'Clone complete'.green
  end

  desc "Fetch and merge from git server, using current checked out branch"
  task :pull do
    puts 'Pulling git'.pink
    sh "cd '#{@source_dir}'; git pull"
    puts 'Pulled'.green
  end

  desc "Shows status of all files in git repo"
  task :status do
    puts 'Showing `git status` of all source files'.pink
    sh "cd #{@source_dir} && git status --short"
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't forget when executing shell commands to **always** use the [`shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) function unless you can specify arguments individually. If `@source_dir` contains a space this will malfunction in a huge way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you just declare dependencies like this:

```
task :pull => :clone do
  # ...
end
```

Or in the case of multiple dependencies:

```
task :status => [ :clone, :pull ] do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: So, how does `pull` know to NOT run `clone` if that directory already exists?

Comment: It will run the step, but as to wether the step does anything or not, that's up to the code contained within it. This just sets up which tasks are triggered.

Comment: This wont work, I can't have a `test` command want to clone a repo, checkout, and build each time if those tasks were already done

Comment: The way Rake works is it will *trigger* tasks in the appropriate order to ensure all dependencies are met, however it's your responsibility as a task implementor to ensure that *only* the required work will be done inside each task. What this means is make your `clone` task check if the directory exists. If it does, your job is done, `return` without doing anything. If not, go at it. Design [idempotent tasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) that are safe to call, quick to run, if they've already done the necessary operations.